# C# Pipe OperationCanceledException when running as a service

Tags: c#, exception, service, pipe

I am developing a windows service application and I'm running into a problem concerning named pipe server. 
The service application has a named pipe service, in order for the GUI to communicate with it - and the GUI has a named pipe client.

When I run the console version of my app (same code but initialized in a console project), everything works fine, but when I run the service version of the app (either installed using setup project or using VS unistallUtil.exe) I get this error:

```
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream.EndWaitForConnection(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Common.PipeCommunication.SomePipeServer.ClientConnected(IAsyncResult ar) in SomePipeServer.cs:line 80
```

This error occurs when I start the service, not even attempting to connect the client to it. Here is my PipeServer Class:

```
public class SomePipeServer
{

    #region PRIVATE VARIABLES
    private string                  _pipeName = "SomePipeServer";
    private NamedPipeServerStream   _pipeServer;
    private IAsyncResult            _connectRequest;
    private byte[] oBuffer;  
    #endregion


    #region PUBLIC VARIABLES
    public event EventHandler MsgReceived;
    #endregion


    #region PUBLIC METHODS
    public SomePipeServer()
    {
        oBuffer = new byte[4096]; 
    }

    public void Start() 
    {
        try
        {
            _pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(
                _pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, -1,
                PipeTransmissionMode.Message,
                PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

            _connectRequest = _pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(
                ClientConnected, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            _connectRequest = null;

            if (_pipeServer == null)
                return;

            if (_pipeServer.IsConnected)
                _pipeServer.Disconnect();

            //_pipeServer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region PRIVATE METHODS
    private void ClientConnected(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ar != null)
            {
                _pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(ar); //line 80
                _connectRequest = null;
                _connectRequest = _pipeServer.BeginRead(oBuffer, 0, 4096,
                    ClientMessage, null);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    private void ClientMessage(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ar != null)
            {
                _pipeServer.EndRead(ar);

                string message = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(oBuffer).Trim(new char[] { '\0', ' ' });
                message = message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ").TrimEnd();

                OnReceive(message);

                _connectRequest = null;
                //_connectRequest = _pipeServer.BeginRead(oBuffer, 0, 4096,
                //    new AsyncCallback(ClientMessage), null);

                //_pipeServer.Disconnect();
                //_pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(ClientConnected, null);
                Stop();
                Start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    private void OnReceive(string in_msg)
    {
        if (MsgReceived != null)
        {
            MsgReceived(in_msg, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a discussion on [this MSDN page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/659c17c9-f809-4118-b74e-fdeb5e7e1f0d/) about (what I've understood) the same problem that you have.

> Windows will complete all overlapped I/O for a thread that has exited, with ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED.
>
> IAsyncResult does not necessarily imply overlapped I/O, but it is a
>   natural fit, and it seems to be the method used by named pipes.
>
> In this case, I would recommend having your main thread create the
>   named pipes; this is normal for a named pipe server (having a separate
>   thread just to create the named pipes is not).

Comment: Thanks for the link Patrik. Since I have to use a Thread to start the PipeService (Windows Service program requires a thread to start the services because it needs the app to respond in less than 5 seconds) I came up a hack to solve the issue. I'll post my solution once I've tested it thoroughly.